# Cultivation manga with a Chinese historical setting, involving a female lead who wakes up in a cage and a monster that is like a virginity tester

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

Things that I remember (not in order):

- Chinese historical romance.
- I also think this was a cultivational manga.
- The female lead woke up in a cage. Later on, a monster that is like a virginity tester (which is feared) was brought to her (I forget the reason why).
- She got a pet qilin (blue) which I think she saved from a cave.
- The female lead found a man trapped for thousands of years. After saving him, the money said that he will kill her (I forget the reason, but I do remember that it was a stupid one).
- Also, the man has a powerful zither (red).
- I think the female lead had a twin sister who is evil?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I didn't understand this part of your description: _"After saving him, the money said that he will kill her."_ Did you mean to say that the _man_ said he will kill her?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, the autocorrect made man to money . A year ago I got a new phone bc my old phone broke, bc of this I was not able to continue reading the manhwas I was reading b4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Poisoning the World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/zn643cu/poisoning-the-world)***...?

> She is the secret service’s trump card, a poison specialist, but also a young and cute girl with a sinister temperament. Contrary to her sweet and innocent appearance, she can complete any tasks without the slightest hesitation. One day because of an incomplete black magic, she was sent into the body of a girl who was deemed as a waste of resources. What kind of change will she bring to this continent?

A secret service agent and poison specialist from the modern world wakes up inside the body of a young girl imprisoned within a cage in a fantasy version of Ancient China.

She has access to the girl's memories as well as her own, and realises that the girl is Ning Xuemo, a duke's orphaned daughter who was engaged to a prince, but has subsequently been imprisoned due to an accusation of adultery, which is considered a capital offense.

The prince asks her if she's willing to confess to the crime she's been accused of, but while she confesses to other things, she denies having committed adultery and insists she was framed, so the prince calls for a "virginity-testing beast" to be wheeled out in another cage.

> [image: Poisoning the World, chapter 3, page 11, 12, 13 and 14.]

This is all within the first three chapters. I've skimmed the first twelve and haven't found the other plot points you mentioned yet, but I believe this is enough to show that this has a good chance of being the story you're looking for.

Comment: Yes this is the manhwa  TYSM FOR YOUR HELP❤